# Magento change sort order of selective categories in Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php, mysql, zend-framework

I am trying to change sort order of sub-categories from the array of category id's following is my code.

```
$catOrder = array(47,54,66,88,89);

$position = 1;

foreach ($catOrder as $catId) {

    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
    if($category->getId()){
        $category->setPosition($position);
        $category->save();        
    } else {
        echo "Could not load category</br>";
        die();
}

$position++;

}
```

The problem is when script is run no error but the result is not as expected. Category changes position though but chose random position not that i wanted.

Comment: Have you tried running the indexer's and cache after running this script?

Comment: Yes i have tried both same result. Is there same thing i am missing

Comment: Your script should work. Is the script actually running? Are you able to check the database and see if the position actually changes? Do your category ids exist?

Comment: Yes the script works fine Ids exists. In the database the value change in the column name as position but in the admin area it doesn't change order

Answer (score 0):

Ok You script should work however, You will need to change the numbers so that the ones you want to appear first at lower. When the category page loads the constructor in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree` sets the following fields:

```
const ID_FIELD    = 'id';
const PATH_FIELD  = 'path';
const ORDER_FIELD = 'order';
const LEVEL_FIELD = 'level';
```

It then calls `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract::getRoot()` which does:

```
$tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')
                ->load(null, $recursionLevel);
```

inside the `Varien_Data_Tree_Dbp::load()` method it does `$select->order($this->_table . '.' . $this->_orderField . ' ASC');`

You will need to change your category position numbers so the items you want to appear at the top need to be as close to 0 and categories to appear at the bottom greater than 0. Hope this makes sense.